# Modifying a Path (string)

Tags: c#, string, properties, replace

I want my program to be able to get the the relevant directory to grab information from a text file to improve robustness.

So this is the method I made:

```
public void GetPath()
{
    var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    hs.Path = directory.Replace(@"\\EventDriven\\bin\\Debug", hs.ReplacePath);
}
```

This is the relevant property and strings (I'm aware I can declare them both in one go):

(Originally the path was hardcoded as you can see)

```
private string path = @"C:\Users\zain\Desktop\program_storage\AccountDatabase.txt";
private const string replacePath = @"Data\AccountDatabase.txt";


public string Path
{
    get { return path; }
    set { this.path = value; }
}

public string ReplacePath { get { return replacePath; } }
```

This is the path I get before I try to replace any of the path:

```
"E:\\Work\\To do\\QA\\program_storage\\program_storage\\bin\\Debug"
```

This is the directory of where the AccountDatbabase.txt file will be in:

```
E:\Work\To do\QA\program_storage\Data
```

So the final directory it should attempt to access is:

```
E:\Work\To do\QA\program_storage\Data\AccountDatabase.txt
```

What seems to get stored in (hs.)Path is

```
"E:\\Work\\To do\\QA\\program_storage\\program_storage\\bin\\Debug"
```

despite usng the replace?

I want the program to work on multiple windows machines. I think I might have a problem with the get set property I made (I'm aware I can remove this. from it) but that should just throw an error? I'm probably not using replace correctly?

Thanks for all and any help provided! (please don't remove this thank you message again)

Comment: Why are you trying to hard code the path, even only a partial path into the application? why not just add a config file or move the test data to the application root?

Comment: @SimonHalsey Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to do the opposite, it was hardcoded and I'm trying to avoid it being hardcoded. Care to elaborate (I'm a novice programmer)? Thanks for your time

Comment: @chrfin That's a different question, I didn't use what was provided as it was completely different from what I asked for

Comment: You can try to use Environment.SpecialFolder. There are a lot of directories for your usage.

Comment: @user3245390: It is a different question, but the solution is still the same. If you want to solve the "replace problem" please rephrase your question...

Comment: @chrfin I wrote this completely differently

Answer (score 0):

Add an app.config file to your application.

Add a `appSettings` section to that file and add a key that contains your file path

When you need the path, call `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["thekeynameyouused"]` to get the path.

Comment: IF done that way, there is no need for the "manual labor": Just add a Settings file via the project properties and then use it via `PROJECT.Properties.Settings.Default.KEY`, but according to the OP's comments thats not the problem he/she actually wants to solve...

Comment: Which does just the same thing, but with slightly stronger typing, but yes also true

Comment: `but with slightly stronger typing` - that the point. The "hard coded string" will build fine if the key is renamed, but crash at runtime. And it is less manuel work using the Settings editor instead of manually editing the app.config - especially for a beginner...

Comment: i know we're splitting hairs, but the renamed key risk exists in both scenarios. It's not really that much more effort with each approach either - roughly the same amount of mouse clicks & key presses.

Comment: My main point is, that your solution will build fine if renamed and crash at runtime, but the other one will fail at build time. A definitve benefit IMO - the rest is just comfort and can be done either way...

Comment: You are almost right. Adding a properties file adds a default value, so if you rename the key in the app.config, your application will still work & use the default value. It will still build though. The only thing that breaks the build is if you rename the key in the properties window because you're then changing code.

Comment: But you shouldn't change the app.config manually if you use the properties file ;-). AND it would recreate the key the next time you change anything in the Settings File Editor...

Comment: There's a lot of things you shouldn't do, but people do them all the time

Comment: True, so true........

Comment: @SimonHalsey Hi, thanks for the response (and thank you to everyone else too). I have a class file with my properties and constants + the path (I will move the properties to another class when I've got this final kink sorted out). I'm not really sure how you'd do that? P.S. Although your way of course is better I'd prefer to do it the way I stated in the OP as it makes sense to me and I understand what I'm doing. In regards to what you've said it makes sense but I don't know how to actually implement it so I'd like more input on how to do it before I attempt it.

Comment: P.S Let me add in I do NOT want the file in appdata, I want the file in the Data folder I made (just extra clarification)

Comment: To the people like @chrfin thank you for not allowing me to get enough help on stackoverflow to do this. I despise when people do this.. I didn't spend time writing these posts for nothing. Nobody providing help is 100% okay but when people do this? Especially when the other topic I had gave a solution that actually doesn't do what I asked? Opening that topic again will mean nobody will post help on it. I know I'm overly annoyed but it's so so so annoying when people are willing to help..

Comment: We ARE willing to help! Hence the active discussions here. BUT you need to ask the correct questions to get the answer you want! If you ask a specific question you will also get a specific answer. But asking for "how to improve robustness" (twice!) and then beeing annoyed for getting solutions for exatly that is not our fault. StackOverflow is a community driven site and it seems "the community" agrees with me, because otherwise you would habe gotten the answer you excpected and not beeing closed...